# Silverlight treeview control selecting the last node and finding the parent?

Tags: silverlight

If I created a silverlight application and used a Treeview control with a HierarchicalDataTemplate with a parent node then a child node under the parent then another child node under the first child node.
If I clicked on the last child node how can I get the path back to the parent?

- Parent

  ```
    Child1
    Child2
           ChildA
    Child3
  ```

So if I had this treeview and I clicked on 'ChildA' is there a way to show that the path is Parent-Child2-ChildA
Thank you

Comment: You can, but it is not so easy. You should bind your tree view to the list of view models, and each view model should have the IsSelected property and the ParentViewModel property. You should rewrite your application in this way.

Comment: Check out the TreeViewExtensions in the Silverlight controls toolkit or Justin Angel's extensions mentioned here:  http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2009/05/19/silverlight-treeview-advanced-scenarios-treeviewextended.aspx

Comment: Since WPF obviously cares less about Parenting issues (a child shouldn't know it's parent, but a parent should know it's children), I would suggest if it is possible for you to give the classes itself Parent properties, could even be an object, it will be the 'cleanest' solution.

Answer (score 0):

Matt... I believe that if you have proper parent-child link (as the one that you have mentioned in your question) & then use recursive calls whenever use clicks any node of your tree then that should serve your purpose. You can give the below logic a try.

UX -

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <sdk:TreeView x:Name="tvGroups" Grid.Row="0">
        <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" Tag="{Binding ItemID}" MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
            </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView>

    <TextBlock x:Name="txbParentToChild" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind -

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
public class Group : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _strItemName;
    private Int32 _itemId;
    private ObservableCollection<Group> _subItems;

    public String ItemName
    {
        get { return _strItemName; }
        set { _strItemName = value; NotifyChange("ItemName"); }
    }

    public Int32 ItemID
    {
        get { return _itemId; }
        set { _itemId = value; NotifyChange("ItemID"); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Group> SubItems
    {
        get { return _subItems; }
        set { _subItems = value; NotifyChange("SubItems"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called whenever any of the Group property is changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="PropertyName">Name of the property that has changed.</param>
    private void NotifyChange(String PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}

public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<Group> _lstItems;
    private Int32 _selectedItemId;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _lstItems = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

        ObservableCollection<Group> childA = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        childA.Add(new Group { ItemID = 1, ItemName = "ChildA", SubItems = null });

        ObservableCollection<Group> parent = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        parent.Add(new Group { ItemID = 2, ItemName = "Child1", SubItems = null });
        parent.Add(new Group { ItemID = 3, ItemName = "Child2", SubItems = childA });
        parent.Add(new Group { ItemID = 4, ItemName = "Child3", SubItems = null });

        _lstItems.Add(new Group { ItemID = 5, ItemName = "Parent", SubItems = parent });

        tvGroups.ItemsSource = _lstItems;
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock txbSource = sender as TextBlock;
        String strItems = String.Empty;
        if (txbSource != null)
        {
            _selectedItemId = -1;
            Int32.TryParse(txbSource.Tag.ToString(), out _selectedItemId);
            List<String> lstParent = new List<String>();
            if (_selectedItemId != -1)
            {
                lstParent = FindItem(_lstItems);
            }
            lstParent.Reverse();
            foreach(String strItem in lstParent)
            {
                strItems += strItem + " -> ";
            }
            strItems = strItems.Remove(strItems.Length - 4);
        }

        txbParentToChild.Text = strItems;
    }

    private List<String> FindItem(ObservableCollection<Group> lstCurrentGroup)
    {
        List<String> lstParent = new List<String>();
        foreach(Group grp in lstCurrentGroup)
        {
            if (grp.ItemID == _selectedItemId)
            {
                lstParent.Add(grp.ItemName);
                return lstParent;
            }
            else if (grp.SubItems != null)
            {
                lstParent = FindItem(grp.SubItems);
                if (lstParent.Count > 0)
                    lstParent.Add(grp.ItemName);
            }
        }
        return lstParent;
    }
}
}
```

Above code displays parent to leaf node link in the TextBlock whenever user clicks on the nodes of the tree.